# How to import components from local js or from a cdn

Tags: angular, typescript

We do have angular2 application, In which we have many components.
We compiled this on server and we generated a JS file using outFile property.

Now we are planning to include this JS in different applications where in the applications can import the components from generated/included JS file.

This is working fine if we are transpiling our application(s) at browser level, But if we need to compile/transpile on server then the we see error saying respective module not found.

**src\app.module.ts(24,8): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'myModuleName'**

Can someone help me on this.

**Current tsconfig:**

```js
var tsProject = ts.createProject({
    emitDecoratorMetaData: true,
    experimentalDecorators: true,
    target: "es5",
    module: "commonjs",
    moduleResolution: "node",
    removeComments: true,
    sourceMap: true,
    outDir: "myBuild"
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    var tsResult = gulp.src('lib/*.ts')
        .pipe(embedTemplates({
            sourceType: "ts",
            basePath: "./",
            minimize: {
                quotes: true
            }
        }))
        .pipe(tsc(tsProject));
});
```

Comment: Can you share TypeScript config?

Comment: Added tsconfig as well, can someone please help me on this.